# Fire event in server from the web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using EF (6) with ASP.net MVC (c#). My hardware architecture:

- main server - include windows service.
- web-server - running my web-application UI.

The users request for some answer. My web-site adds the question to the Data-Base (SQL - server) with EF.

In my main server, the service detects the changes (new task arrived) and solve it.

**The detection of new task made by busy waiting, which I do not like.**

How it's being done:

1. My EF layer includes custom function, which fire every N minutes SQL stored procedure.
2. If the SP retrieve information, the service solve it.

**What I want:** 
when new task added from the web-site, the web-site will **send signal** to the main server. When the signal arrives to the main server, it will immediately start to solve it.

How this can be done?

Thank you!

Comment: seems like a perfect use case for singalR....http://www.asp.net/signalr

Comment: SignalR is looking good! But, there are any advantage of using SignalR instead of using sockets \ wcf? performance?

Comment: yes because signalR will choose the best suited communication method. it also uses sockets if available otherwise fallback to other means of transport.

Comment: Great. Please post your message as "answer" and i'll mark it as chosen solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like a perfect use case for singalR....

please take a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr

signalR will choose the best suited communication method. it also uses sockets if available otherwise fallback to other means of transport.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more service for Comm. between two servers . 
Solution implemented with WCF is very trivial to Develop ..

Whenever new Question is posted .. your webserver can invoke  this webservice ..

bottom - line :  Look into WCF

Answer (score 0):

We do this a lot, I think you have a few options:

- A shared storage mechanism which is polled from the receiver (what you are currently doing)
- Using something like a webservice call to send a command to the receiver (Normally a synchronous processing technique)
- Using a messaging framework such as NServicebus to send the command to the receiver (an asynchronous fault tolerant technique)

We use all of these techniques, but the one I normally find best is the last one.

Messaging introduces fault tolerance and asynchronous processing which are both very useful when building systems spanning multiple machines.

If this sounds like something that might help check out the pubsub example for NServiceBus here: http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/860297-how-pub-sub-works

Or if fault tolerance doesn't really matter to you I would recommend a selfhosted webapi running inside your windows service.